# SVN commit "update version" echo %xprvar%

Tags: jenkins, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to commit to SVN through a batch command line in Jenkins:

```
svn commit "update version" echo %xprvar% .
```

`xprvar` is a version variable I set as Environment variable. But when run, the SVN commit message is `update version echo %xprvar%`, so the variable does not display its value. Can you please advise how I can sort out this one?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please isolate and format the commands you are using. Please be precise and specific, this is not a storytelling service. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am working on Dev Ops concepts and When i am automated application version name and assign the application version name to variable.

Comment: I am working on Dev Ops concepts and When i am automated application version name and assign the application version name to variable. now i am trying to pass the same variable during svn commit phase. hers is my command . ---  svn commit "update version 'echo %variable%'" echo %variable%. but when i given this command  command line doest take the value and not showing the result . please help me on this

Comment: Is it a pipeline or freestyle job? Where do you set the environment variable?

Comment: it is a freestyle job. I had set the environment variable in command line.

Comment: The below code was to set the environment variable in our environment                 set "xprvar3="
for /F "skip=11 delims=" %%i in (C:\app\output.txt) do set "xprvar=%%i"&goto nextline
:nextline